# Draw the graphs of the following functions and calculate the main characteristics (zeros, axis intercepts, maxima, minima, etc.).

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, statistics, functions

a) $\boldsymbol{1}_{\{x \leq 2 \}} (x)$

b) $2 \cdot \boldsymbol{1}_{\{-2 \leq x \leq -0.5 \}} (x) - 1$

c) $ax + b$ with $a, b > 0$

d) $5x^2$

e) $-2x^3 + x$

---

Drawing the graphs on this site seems a bit complicated, but I can find the main characteristics (zeros, axis intercepts, maxima, minima, etc.)

a) The indicator function has the value $1$ for $x \leq 2$, and $0$ otherwise. So the zeros of the function are where $ x > 2$. The function also lies on the x axis there, and intersection with y axis at $f(0) = 1$. As far as I know, this function has no maxima or minima

b) The function has the value $1$ for $-2 \leq x \leq -0.5 $, and $-1$ otherwise. Intersection with x axis at $x = -2$ and $x = -0.5$, and intersection with y axis at $f(0) = -1$. As far as I know, this function has no maxima or minima

c) Linear equation with zero at $x = -b/a$. It's also where the function intersects the x axis. The y axis intersection is at $f(0) = a \cdot 0 + b = b$. As far as I know, a linear equation has no maxima or minima

d) Zero and intersection with x axis: $5x^2 = 0 \rightarrow x = 0$. Intersection with y axis at $f(0) = 0$.

Derivative: $10x = 0 \rightarrow x = 0$ Plugging in at $x=0$, we notice a local minima

e) Zeroes and intersection with x axis : $x = 0$ and $-2x^2 + 1 = 0 \rightarrow x = \pm 1/\sqrt{2}$

Intersection with y axis at $f(0) = 0$

Derivative: $-6x^2 + 1 = 0 \rightarrow x = \pm 1/\sqrt{6}$

Looking at the graph of the function in Google, we see a local maxima at $1/\sqrt{6}$ and local minima at $-1/\sqrt{6}$

---

Could you review my attempt ? We have no solutions so I can't know what is correct and what not. Thanks for your help !

PS: Also, do you know a website where the graph of an indicator function can easily be drawn ? For c), d) and e), I can find their graph directly on google, but a) and b) I don't see how and where I can draw their graph online. Is it maybe possible somehow on Wolfram Alpha or Desmos ?

Comment: All looks correct **But**  b) "Intersection with x axis at x=−2
 and x=−0.5" is false : the curve doesn't intersect the $x$ axis.
,"

Comment: On Desmos `f_{1}\left(x\right)=1\left\{x\le2\right\}` and `f_{2}=0\left\{x>2\right\}` will give you two lines which combined are the indicator function $\boldsymbol{1}_{\{x \leq 2 \}} (x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) the maxima is attained on $(-\infty, 2]$ and the minima is attained on $(2, \infty)$.

Similar for b, maxima and minima exist.

c) an affine equation with positive slope has no  minima and no maxima as it is an increasing function.